# Error message when trying to save my created Excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to create an Excel file in C# with Interop. I've created the basic formatting and was about to draw data from my SQL database but first wanted to be sure it works fine.

Every time I try to save the file, I get the general

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

message. I've searched far and wide for a solution and tried everything I can but I can't seem to get it to work. It gives me an error message when it reaches the SaveAs line.

Below is my code for the `void` function that creates the Excel file:

```
public static void createFile()
{
    //Figures out how many days are in the month
    string month = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\noahc\Documents\TimesheetInvoiceMonth\month.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
    string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    int intYear = Convert.ToInt32(year);
    int columns;

    if (month == "September" || month == "April" || month == "June" || month == "November")
    {
        columns = 34;
    }
    else if (month == "January" || month == "March" || month == "May" || month == "July" || month == "August"
        || month == "October" || month == "December")
    {
        columns = 35;
    }
    else if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(intYear))
        columns = 33;
    else
        columns = 32;

    //Create excel application
    Excel._Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbooks xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    xlApp.Visible = true;

    xlApp.StandardFont = "Arial Narrow";
    xlApp.StandardFontSize = 10;

    //Format top row
    xlSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "monthly time sheet | lee calisti";
    xlSheet.Cells[1, "A"].Font.Size = 14;
    xlSheet.Cells[1, "A"].Font.Color = Color.White;

    //colNames is an array of column names
    string[] colNames = new string[columns];

    //Entering column names into array
    colNames[0] = month + " " + year;
    colNames[2] = "date";

    for (int i = 3; i < columns - 1; i++)
    {
        colNames[i] = (i - 2).ToString();
        xlSheet.Columns[i + 1].ColumnWidth = 4.25;
    }

    colNames[columns - 1] = "Project";
    string lastColumn;
    switch (columns)
    {
        case 32:
            lastColumn = "AF";
            break;
        case 33:
            lastColumn = "AG";
            break;
        case 34:
            lastColumn = "AH";
            break;
        case 35:
            lastColumn = "AI";
            break;
        default:
            lastColumn = "A";
            MessageBox.Show("Something is wrong...");
            break;
    }
    //Back color of first row
    xlSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(197, 90, 17);

    //Date on last column of first row
    DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
    xlSheet.Cells[1, lastColumn] = thisDay.ToString("d");
    xlSheet.Cells[1, lastColumn].Font.Color = Color.White;

    //Second row
    xlSheet.get_Range("A2", lastColumn + "2").Value2 = colNames;
    xlSheet.get_Range("A2", "C2").Font.Bold = true;
    xlSheet.get_Range("B2", lastColumn + "2").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
    xlSheet.Columns[1].AutoFit();

    //Third row
    xlSheet.Cells[3, lastColumn] = "Total Hours";

    //Project name, phase, and number headings
    xlSheet.Cells[4, "C"] = "project";
    xlSheet.Cells[4, "C"].Font.Bold = true;
    xlSheet.Cells[5, "A"] = "project name";
    xlSheet.Cells[5, "B"] = "phase";
    xlSheet.Cells[5, "C"] = "number";
    xlSheet.get_Range("A5", "C5").Font.Bold = true;
    xlSheet.get_Range("B4", "C5").HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
    xlSheet.Columns[columns].AutoFit();

    // Save the excel file at specified location
    xlWorkbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\noahc\OneDrive\Documents\NOAH\TestSave\test.xlsx");

    //Cleanup
    xlWorkbook.Close(true);
    xlApp.Quit();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlSheet);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything right off-hand. To trouble-shoot this, try commenting out everything staritng with `xlApp.StandardFont = "Arial Narrow";` through `xlSheet.Columns[columns].AutoFit();` and see if that runs. Then remove the comments from a few lines and run again until you isolate the part that's triggering the error. Also, note that COM objects should be released in the reverse order they were instantiated - IOW reverse that list at the end. `xlSheet`, for example, depends on everything above it. Releasing in the wrong order can leave things "hanging".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have issues with the "Arial Narrow" font. Not only did this cause issues saving the file, but it made it such that I couldn't open *any* Excel files (because running this script changed the default font for Excel - not just the font for this workbook)!

This can cause especially difficult to debug issues because you can't just comment out the lines and try again, as you've actually changed the state of the installed Excel application.

What ended up working for me was to go into Excel options, and change the default font back to Arial. Then, as suggested, comment out as many lines as possible, working backwards until you've isolated the issue.

Again, the specific note I have to add is that when you change properties on xlApp, you are creating side effects at the application level. Make sure you've restored defaults, then proceed with debugging your script.

Comment: That's strange. I'll try it but I'll also say that I have been able to use Excel perfectly fine on other files. This program will create the file perfectly too, it just throws an error when attempting to save.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue when trying to save a file to a OneDrive location when the document has AutoSave set, and OneDrive set to
[Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYA4Y.png).

Files save fine if they are not to OneDrive locations.

To get the files to save with no issues:

- Uncheck "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open."
- Open the file in its saved location and set Autosave off and save again.
- I also have found that setting ["Always keep on this device"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRr3d.png) in File Explorer also helps.

I realise this isn't especially helpful, as it is manual steps outside the code, but I thought I would post this if it helps anyone.